# High percentage of ajax errors

Tags: iis, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

My company's website uses jQuery ajax to submit forms. A high percentage (5% - 10%) are failing, causing the ajax's error handler to run in the client's browser. The error handler looks like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'post',
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (developmentMode) return;
        $.post('/error/LogAjaxError', { err: 'headers:' + (request.getAllResponseHeaders ? request.getAllResponseHeaders() : '') });
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.href = (appRoot + 'error/500');
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

`error/LogAjaxError` successfully logs these errors, which is how we know the percentage. Now it's not a server error, because

1. we are using Elmah, (which normally works great,) but is not catching any error on these ajax calls
2. we can see that the ajax server code ran until the end without error, as it adds a db record in the last line

It is also unlikely to be a network issue, since the client successfully sends an ajax call to `error/LogAjaxError` a few ms later.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue could be, since it doesn't seem to be a server or a network error?

Mostly the clients are using mobile devices. Are there any statistics as to what percentage of ajax requests from mobile devices are expected to fail?